# Auto Populate custom field on change of look up field

Tags: case, autocomplete

I have a simple text custom field and I want to auto populate the value in it on basis of a lookup field value.
To be more precise, in case object when a user selects contact, I want to auto populate the email address of the contact in a separate field instantly and not on save.
I have seen this question many times but could not find a solution which can help me
I cannot use a formula field because it is not visible in edit section and this will confuse users.
Any solution without APEX involvement would really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formula field does sound like the right item here, and I'm not sure I fully understand your concern about the users being confused. Do you want users to have the ability to "override" the autopopulated email from the contact by being able to edit the field?

If this is your use case, you could have a second field on the Contact that you could populate which could propagate to the formula field. If this local field is not populated, the formula field could default to the contact's email. Something like this:

```
IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Local_Email_Field__c)),
    Local_Email_Field__c,
    Contact_Lookup_Field__r.Email__c
)
```

If you don't have a use case for the override, I would simply train your users that the field won't appear on the edit layout and to not worry about it.